# Changing a text input field value with jQuery when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to dynamically change a text input's value between 1 and 0 if a certain checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#input_7_37_1').click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery("#input_7_55").val( "0" );
        } else {
            jQuery("#input_7_55").val( "1" );
        }
    });
});
```

`#input_7_37_1` is the ID of the checkbox whose value (checked or unchecked) that I'm interested in. `#input_7_55` is the ID of the text input field I want to change the value to either 1 or 0. The default value of `#input_7_55` is 1.

When I check `#input_7_37_1`, the value of `#input_7_55` remains 1, when I am trying to get it to change to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .prop() like so:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#input_7_37_1').click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
            jQuery("#input_7_55").val( "0" );
        } else {
            jQuery("#input_7_55").val( "1" );
        }
    });
});
```

Bonus rewrite:

```
$(function () {
    $('#input_7_37_1').click(function() {
        $("#input_7_55").val( $(this).prop("checked") ? "0" : "1" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I feel like a dummy. There was an error from another script on the page that was breaking the script I posted. What I had worked once the error was corrected. Your solution worked too though. Thanks!